# Why Elasticsearch running only first time after install?

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed Elasticsearch using installer, after that I executed elasticsearch.exe file, it starts running at port 9200 at localhost. Then I kill the process at 9200 port (to stop elasticsearch service). When I executed elasticsearch.exe again it's giving an error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class 3400\AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch

Comment: Witch environment ? windows i thinck?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10. @LeBigCat

Comment: This is a java error. Can you check your environement variable (for java reference), also try to start elastic from comman (from java.exe directoty)